# How is `--coverage-html` different from `--coverage-clover`?

Tags: phpunit, clover

How is `--coverage-html` different from `--coverage-clover`?

The following is the output after calling `phpunit --coverage-clover ./clover.xml` on my project.

```
<metrics files="39" loc="3550" ncloc="2528" 
         classes="38" methods="138" coveredmethods="66" 
         conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="1302"
         coveredstatements="549" elements="1440" coveredelements="615"/>
```

You might notice the loc vs. the ncloc. But when I run `phpunit --coverage-html ./$path`, I get

```
| Lines                 | 42.17% covered (danger)   | 549 / 1302
| Functions and Methods | 47.83% covered (danger)   | 66 / 138
| Classes and Traits    | 44.74% covered (danger)   | 17 / 38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this, the HTML coverage is equating to *statements* in Clover. Meanwhile Clover is counting actually executed lines of Code. So while HTML will mark [this file](https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-example/blob/master/app/Jobs/Job.php) as covered, since that class isn't executed (in this set of tests), then Clover does not consider it covered.

Answer (score 0):

XML can be used in PHPClover in Jenkins to print coverage raport, HTML can be viewed from browser via ftp connecton.

Haven't seen other differences

Comment: The question was the difference between LOC in clover and LOC in HTML. They are measured differently.

Comment: aa didn't see that between two block sorry my bad